# Formating of Pseudo code

Tags: algorithm2e, code, pseudocode

I have the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\label{alg:algo1}

\KwIn{Objects $O1...On$}
\KwOut{$true$, falls Mehrheitsvotum besteht, sonst $false$}

$counter\leftarrow0$\;
\For {$i=1$ \thinspace to n}{
    \For {$j=1$ \thinspace to n}{
     \If {$O_1=O_j$}{
     $counter \leftarrow counter+1$}
    }
}
\If {$counter\geq n/2$}{
return $true$}
\Else {return $false$}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, there are some vertical lines for every for or if and it says "end" when the loop is over. Can I get rid of the lines and the end? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the manual, section 7.4 says:

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,noline,noend]{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: ok thanks. Where can I find this manual?

Comment: @Cherry Run `texdoc algorithm2e` in a terminal/command prompt on your computer, download it from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e?lang=en), or find it on [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net).

Comment: @Cherry By the way, if you get answers to your questions that solve your problem, consider accepting one of them, by clicking the checkmark next to it (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1).